# ArrayList error: invalid constructor;

Tags: c++, arraylist, c++98

I am a beginner, some do not know why this error is, how it should look like?

All code: http://pastebin.com/6j0H0wEN

Its source code implementation on ArrayList:

> error: expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token
>
> error: invalid constructor; you probably meant 'ArrayList (const ArrayList&)'
> In constructor 'ArrayList::ArrayList()':

```
ArrayList<T> (const ArrayList<T> & that) : capacity_(that.capacity_), size_(that.size_) {
    data_ = new T[capacity_];
    memcpy(data_, that.data_, sizeof(T) * size_);
}

ArrayList<T> (const ArrayList<T>&& that) : capacity_(that.capacity_), size_(that.size_) {
    data_ = that.data_;
    that.data_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what error says: you don't need <T> everywhere: `ArrayList (const ArrayList & that)` instead is ok.

Comment: It's still bad.
error: invalid constructor; you probably meant 'ArrayList<T> (const ArrayList<T>&)'
 In constructor 'ArrayList<T>::ArrayList()':

Comment: I'm actually sorry for commenting before testing, here I tried your code from pastebin compiling with c++14: [link](http://ideone.com/UYRLwV) looks like everything was fine.

Comment: Yea, but i must run this on c++98 and i don't know how to do this.

Comment: well, `const ArrayList<T>&& that` is move semantics from `c++11` so you cannot use it in `c++98`

Comment: So what can i change this ?

Comment: You cannot use features of move semantics - remove that constructor. Btw, `nullptr` is also from `c++11` and up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the second constructor to be

```
ArrayList<T> (ArrayList<T>&& that)
```

with no `const`. Otherwise you cannot steal the content of the `that` list.

---

Oh, and also if you actually use `c++98` you don't have move constructors at all.

Answer (score 0):

Rvalue references in C++98 are not going to work; period. They do not exist.